# How to show data from AsyncStorage variable

Tags: react-native

I'm newbie for react-native.

I used AsyncStorage to store "My Name" successfully but when I get "My Name" it's not show in screen. The result order of logging is "-" and "My Name"
you can check my code below

```js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
    import { Text } from 'react-native';
    
    let user_name = '-';
    
    const getName = async () => {  
        const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('name_key')
        return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;  
    }
    
    const Welcome = () => {
    
      getName().then((keyValue) => {
        user_name = keyValue.name;
        console.log(user_name);  // This log is "My Name" that I stored before
     });
     
     console.log(user_name);  // This log is "-" that I defined >> let user_name = '-';
    
      return(<Text> Welcome {user_name} </Text>)
    
    };
    
    export default Welcome;
```

output log order is

```
-
My Name
```

and a screen show "-"
I want it to show "My Name"

look like it's not wait, getName () to finish process and render before it complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using state to rerender it?

```
const Welcome = () => {
  const [name,setname] = useState('-')

  useEffect(() => {  
     getName().then((keyValue) => {
       setname(keyValue.name);
     });
    //use effect will run after the screen complete render,
    //and rerender if there is a state change
  },[]);

  return(<Text> Welcome {name} </Text>)

};

export default Welcome;
```

Comment: Oh yes Thank you!

Comment: you can learn more about react hook (lyfecycle). i use this site when i am still learning react native. https://react-hooks-cheatsheet.com